# How remove mdiChild form shrink button?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, mdichild, mdiparent

I already disabled maximize and minimize buttons. Now i want to remove shrink button. How can i do that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this code in the LoadEvent form the form:

```
base.MinimizeBox = false;
```

or

```
this.MinimizeBox = false;
```